# Bash/Python Compare 2 CSV Files Output to .htaccess Redirects

Tags: python, bash, .htaccess, csv, redirect

I have 2 CSV files.  Both contain all the URL's attached to 2 websites.

1 is live, the second is in development.

The problem I am currently facing is, site #2's URL's are formatted a bit differently, so in the interest of SEO, I need to generate a bunch of 301 HTaccess Redirects, comparing the URL's from the 2 CSV files.

I'm not really worried too much about the .htaccess output, as I can always just append the `redirect` stuff after the fact, but how can I compare the 2 CSV's, and if the URL in CSV1 is `LIKE` the URL in CSV2, and output the line to a 3rd file in a:

`URL1 URL`

Type of format?

**For instance:**

CSV1 Contains:

```
http://url1/the-page-1
http://url1/the-page-2
http://url1/the-page-3
http://url1/the-page-4
```

CSV2 Contains:

```
http://url2/someplace/the-page-1
http://url2//someotherplace/the-page-2
http://url2/the-page-3
http://url2/andyetanotherplace/the-page-4
```

And output to:

```
http://url1/the-page-1 http://url2/someplace/the-page-1
http://url1/the-page-2 http://url2//someotherplace/the-page-2
http://url1/the-page-3 http://url2/the-page-3
http://url1/the-page-4 http://url2/andyetanotherplace/the-page-4
```

REAL DATA, and OUTPUT of `awk -F/ 'NR == FNR {a[$NF]=$0; next} $NF in a {print a[$NF], $0 > "combined.csv"}' old-site.csv new-site.csv` is uploaded to: [Upload](https://mega.nz/#F!TkJXBIyS!tOeEvGwzRYqIdGmCBJ3csg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {gsub(/\/$/, ""); $NF=tolower($NF)} NR==FNR{a[$NF]=$0; next}
     $NF in a {print a[$NF] " " $0 > "combined.csv"}' old-site.csv new-site.csv


cat combined.csv

http://url1/the-page-1 http://url2/someplace/the-page-1
http://url1/the-page-2 http://url2//someotherplace/the-page-2
http://url1/the-page-3 http://url2/the-page-3
http://url1/the-page-4 http://url2/andyetanotherplace/the-page-4
```

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: Any ideas how I can now remove the matched links from old-site and new-site?  Or should I do that as a new question ;)

Comment: Yes please, post a new question.